# Why Don't I have "On Update" constraints in my "Relation View" on PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cascade, relation

I'm working on a database with many related tables and I recently learned (yesterday) that in order for my related columns to update automatically when I make changes to the PARENT key, I need to set the relation up with "On Update" constraints. However, the more I research on how to do this through my PHPMyAdmin interface, the more I realize that I'm missing something in my version of PHPMyAdmin.

Apparently I should be able to do this through "Relation View" under my "Structure" tab. Problem is, I don't have that option (See img)

[image]

What you see is all that's available on that page.

After digging around a little bit more, I realized that if I go through my "Designer" Page (see img):

[image]

Then I'm able to access something that actually talks about "On Update" (see img)

[image]

The only problem now is that I can't seem to "Create" my Relations with "On Update" because these foreign relations already exist. (Head-Desks)

**Questions:**

1.)Why do I not have the "ON UPDATE" option under my "Relation View" Where it is apparently supposed to be? I'm using **MAMP 3.2.1** and **PHPMyAdmin 4.4.1.1** (latest version) and my Storage Engine is **InnoDB**.

2.)Given that, is there any way outside of using SQL that I can add the "ON UPDATE" constraints through my PHPMyAdmin interface to my already existing foreign keys?

3.)If not, what would be the SQL that I'd need in order to do this "By Hand". Generic examples would be fine.

**UPDATE:**

So I decided to try and remove some of my relations in order to re-connect them with the DESIGNER interface which appeared to have what I wanted. However, when I did so and attempted to create the connection, I got this:

[image]

What happened to my "ON UPDATE" options?!

Comment: @RyanVincent - I don't quite understand what you're talking about. What I'm trying to do here is that when I update one of my parent keys (for example, I noticed yesterday that one had a typo), I want that change to cascade down to any foreign keys related to it. Based on what I've read, I do this through "On Update Cascade", which is what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to figure out my problem. Well, not my ***problem***, I still don't know why I don't have CONSTRAINT fields in my RELATION VIEW in PHPMyAdmin. But I was able to figure out a way around it. **Jiji John** suggested that I download MySQL Workbench, which I did but couldn't figure out how to work at first. Then I realized the reason it wasn't working was because I was making tons of mistakes. Which makes sense, I'm still pretty new at this. But I'm still not very comfortable with the MySQL Workbench interface. I don't feel it's as intuitive as PHPMyAdmin.

So this is what I did to convert ALL my (many) tables to ON UPDATE CASCADE. I'm sure there was a more efficient way to do this, but at least this got it done:

1. Since all SQL attempts seemed to be having issues with all my current tables, I individually copied each table one-by-one to a new database through PHPMyAdmin's Operations Tab.

   First, I copied the Referenced Tables that didn't have any foreign keys, to which I added the prefix NFK (No Foreign Keys) so I'd have a visual reference of which tables I didn't need to mess with.

[image]
[image]

2. After I'd copied over all my NFK tables, I worked on the remaining tables in the order that required the fewest to largest amounts of foreign keys.
3. First I'd copy just the table **structure** (no data) from the first database to the 2nd one.
   [image]
4. Then I'd head over to MySQL Workbench to add the necessary foreign keys and ON UPDATE constraints since PHPMyAdmin won't do that for me.
   [image]
5. After that I would copy the export SQL from the original table and paste it into the SQL field of the 2nd database.

[image]

[image][image]

6. Finally I would add the prefix OUC (On Update Cascade) to the new table so I'd know I was done with it, and then I'd hide the table on the old database so I'd know I was done with THAT.

[image]

I know this is a bit graphic heavy, but I'm a very visual person, especially when it comes to things I don't understand. So I hope all these graphics will help someone who was having trouble like I was. I do appologies for how large the images are. I was simply taking screen shots from my computer, I'm not sure how I'd make them smaller . . .

Answer (score 1):

I had lot of issues like this with phpmyadmin. So i recommend you to Download Mysql workbench and use it instead of phpmyadmin. Work bench is way better than php my admin. Download it here

https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: If I were to download the MySQL workbench, how would I go about connecting my MAMP and local host to it?

Comment: it's easy , create a new connection and add your hostname, mysql host, port and credentials . then click connect ..

Comment: I downloaded the workbench and was actually able to connect it with my current database pretty easy. However, I've found it to be very buggy, not actually running it's own SQL queries and it's already crashed twice.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that MySQL Workbench wasn't working because I was messing all sorts of things up. Once I figured out what I needed to do, it stopped acting stupid (Imagine that). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using `MyIsam` as storage engine.

That doesn't support foreign key constraints. Looking at a `MyIsam` table in any of my databases gives me the same as your screenshot.

Same server, same database, but `innodb` engine gives:[image: this]

Comment: @Axel Amthor - If you can see this img, you'll see that all my tables are InnoDB 

http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn12/ladyesori1/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-11%20at%2010.34.21%20AM_zpskhqvmuln.png

Comment: Did you check this http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_relation setting?